# How use c# variable as id for div and then as argument for javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a div from every object in my model, and I need to give them unique IDs for the onclick-method. How do I do this? I tried to put myid inside <%= %> as I read somewhere, it does not work.

This is my code:

```
@foreach(var r in Model){
   var myid = r.ToString();

   <p class="expand-one" onclick="showhide('<%= myid  %>')" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">@r.ToSection.Name</p>
               <table id=@myid class="content-one">
                   <tr>
            ......................
             ..................
```

Comment: Do you need ids at all?  Instead of passing `<%= myid %>` you could pass `this.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]` (the element rather than the string id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Razor's `@` in the same manner you use it in `@r.ToSection.Name`:

```
<p class="expand-one" onclick="showhide('@myid')"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use this, so you can try
`<p class="expand-one" onclick="showhide('@(myid)')"></p>`

Comment: You may want to elaborate your answer to be more holistic within a solution.